# Setting env variables on openshift 4 and spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, environment-variables, openshift

I am using spring boot application which needs to be deployed to the openshift 4. I have a private image registry created. The openshift pulls image from this private repository.
I have set the env variables in spring profile (named openshift) in the  spring boot application as follows:

- applicaton-openshift.yaml

spring:
datasource:
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//${DB_URL}
username: ${DB_USERNAME}
password: ${DB_PASSWORD}

the datasource properties are set as env variables in intellij idea.
Now whenever I deploy the application to openshift. the spring application takes the profile as default and ignore this openshift profile.

Can anyone suggest where I am doing wrong?
and **oc env** command does not work for me in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide details of your applicaton-openshift.yaml
but in Openshift you can set environment variables in "ENV" section for your container.

Usually Spring merge environment variables and java properties and you can override property value with environment variable, but I am not sure which version of Spring started to do this.

In very legacy, you can set JAVA_OPS or JAVA_OPS_APPEND variable with " -Dmy.property=my.valye " in openshift deployconfig.